# How to get child test case pathname in Katalon Studio

Tags: katalon-studio

If you're reading this question, chances are that you already know how to get pathname of a test case in Katalon Studio :

`RunConfiguration.getExecutionSourceId()`

However, that doesn't seem to work on child test cases. For example, in my case, I have some child test case, whose path is `Test Cases/New Zoho/Member Lead/New Zoho - Member Lead`, being called from parent test case `Test Cases/New Zoho/New Zoho - 02 Create Practice`. It is in a benchmark handler class, that create the benchmark file if it doesn't already exist, using the test case pathname.

The `New Zoho - Member Lead` test case has some code that ends up using `RunConfiguration.getExecutionSourceId()`. When I put debug breakpoint at that line, and run it, I see `Test Cases/New Zoho/New Zoho - 02 Create Practice`. and not the name of the child test case. It ends up creating `New Zoho/New Zoho - 02 Create Practice.xlsx` instead of appending to the already-existing `New Zoho/Member Lead/New Zoho - Member Lead.xlsx` in the benchmark data folder...

How do I get the child test case name here instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do something like this:

`RunConfiguration.getExecutionProperties().get("current_testcase")`

to get the id of the current test case context, even if that test case is a child test case...